# Django-Tastypie custom paginator

Tags: django, rest, pagination, tastypie

I've created my own Resource on my Django-Tastypie API.
I've been implementing some rest operations and now i would like to implement my custom paginator, that will generate next/prev values based on a "key" passed by url.

The problem is: if i pass a value like "http:localhost:8000/api/stats/list/nextpage/", the obj_get is automatically called and don't let me return a list of values, only one value.

So i want that obj_get returns more than one value.
My api.py looks like this:

My Resource class:

```
class CountryCountResource(Resource):

   countryName= fields.CharField(attribute='countryName')
   countryCount = fields.FloatField(attribute='countryCount')

   class Meta:
       resource_name = 'country/list'
       object_class = dict2obj
       include_resource_uri = False
       authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
       authentication = BasicAuthentication()

   def detail_uri_kwargs(self, bundle_or_obj):
       kwargs = {}

       if isinstance(bundle_or_obj, Bundle):
           kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.obj.countryName
       else:
           kwargs['pk'] = bundle_or_obj.countryName

       return kwargs

   def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):

       db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxxxxx',user='xxx',passwd='xxx',db='xxx')
       cur = db.cursor()
       cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM users")
       total_users=cur.fetchall()
       for item in total_users:
           totalint=int(item[0])

       cur.execute("SELECT country,count(country) FROM users GROUP BY country ORDER BY    count(country) DESC LIMIT 0,10")

       #ordered tuple
       mylist=cur.fetchall()

       newlist=[]
       for i in mylist:
           auxd={}
           auxd['countryName']=str(i[0])
           res=int(i[1])/float(totalint)
           res="%.2f" % res
           auxd['countryCount']=res
           newlist.append(dict2obj(auxd))

       db.close()

       return newlist

   def obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
       return newlist <<<<<<------- DONT WORK
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use or customize the paginator behavior that comes with any `ModelResource` by default: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/paginator.html